# Restoring a snapshot containing expired data

Tags: cassandra

I have a snapshot of a production system that I want to restore into a test system to recreate a problem, easy so far. One of the tables contains data with a TTL that has expired now because the snapshot is a few weeks old.

The restore works fine using sstableloader, destination cluster has a different topology. After the restore cfstats show I have key entries in the table.

As soon as I query the table the rows are expired as the TTL is in the past and I get 0 results.

Is there any way I can get the TTL reset as part of the restore? I'm using Cassandra 3 so the [TTLRemover](https://github.com/instaclustr/TTLRemover) tool is not usable.

Comment: A quick and dirty solution - fake your system clock before restoring.

Comment: another possible approach is to change `expired at` attribute in sstabledump file

Comment: How do you change the attribute in the sstables?

Comment: Check this out - https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse-trblshoot/doc/troubleshooting/recoveringTtlYear2038Problem.html